# Multiple Lava Pumps In The Nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have setup a 4 lava pumps to pump out lava in the nether to a tank in the overworld. Unfortunatley only one pump is working despite having the exact same setups. Is there a limit to how many pumps you can have in one chunk? I have provided a screenshot of my setup.[image]

As you can probably (or not) see, they have exactly the same setups. Each with the exact same I/O's. Anyone have any idea how to get them all to work? They all seem to be pumping but in the three that aren't working, no lava is being inputted into the magmatic engine.

Comment: This will sound like a stupid question in the Nether, but is there lava beneath each pump?
Also, by "seem to be pumping" you mean there is the motion, but no output, right?

Comment: yes there is lava beneath each pump. And yes there is motion in the magmatic engines and the pipes are being produced under the pumps.

Comment: use an MJ reader and make sure all of the redstone energy conduits are recieving flow? It seems like the one you have working is correctly set up, but on the others you missed a wrench somewhere and its causing the circuit to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question you are allowed to have as many pumps as you want near each other. Why your setup isn't working probably has to do with energy distribution.

You can test for yourself with multiple pumps in a chunk by making a super flat world and testing there in creative mode.